# How to serialize two parameter Json convert?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin, asp.net-web-api, json.net

I have a xamarin forms app and a REST web api created using ASP.net. The web api is running on the remote server. In that web api, I have classes for my database queries. I need to pass the server address, username, password and database name as connection string from my xamarin app to that particular class. How to serialize both the connection string and the object together?

My database query

```
public void addSalesReport(string connstr, SalesReport salesreport)
    {

        MySqlConnection myconn = new MySqlConnection(connstr);
        string d = salesreport.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        String sqlstr = "INSERT INTO salesreport (ID,sDate,ColorCopy,BwCopy,4RPrints,Misc,ExternalOrder,TotalSales,BwWastage,ColorWastage,Remarks) VALUES ('" + salesreport.ID + "','" + d + "'," + salesreport.ColorCopy + "," + salesreport.BwCopy + "," + salesreport.p4rPrint + "," + salesreport.Misc + ","+salesreport.ExternalOrder+","+salesreport.TotalSales+","+salesreport.BwWastage+","+salesreport.ColorWastage+",'"+salesreport.Remarks+"')";
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(sqlstr, myconn);
        myconn.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myconn.Close();
        myconn.Dispose();

    }
```

Control to post data to Mysql db

```
 [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/SalesReport", Name = "salesReport")]
    public void PostUpdate([FromBody]string connstr , SalesReport value)
    {
        SalesDBConn db = new SalesDBConn();
        db.addSalesReport(connstr, value);
    }
```

Data service class in my Xamarin app

```
public async void addSalesReport(string connstr, SalesReport salesReport)
    {
        var conn = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(connstr);
        var contentstr = new StringContent(conn, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(salesReport);
        var content =  new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        var response = await client.PostAsync("http://myserverdomain.com/api/SalesReport", contentstr, content);

    }
```

Comment: I am getting error on content in await client.PostAsync("http://myserverdomain.com/api/SalesReport", contentstr, content); 
Cannot convert from system.net.http.stringContent to System.Threading,CancellationToken

Comment: I don't see the type of `client` object? Is it defined outside `addSalesReport` method?

Comment: yes its outside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first, we will have to introduce a new class which will act as wrapper container for your two inputs. Now whenever we serialize the class, both the inputs will get serialized together:

```
public class DataToPost
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public SalesReport SalesReportData { get; set; }
}
```

Then change the `addSalesReport` method as shown in the code snippet below:

```
public async void addSalesReport(string connstr, SalesReport salesReport)
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    var objectDataToPost = new DataToPost { ConnectionString = connstr, SalesReportData = salesReport };
    var data = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(objectDataToPost);
    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    
    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://myserverdomain.com/api/SalesReport", content, CancellationToken.None);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

So you're going to embed the connection string to your database into your clients? That sounds like a really bad idea.

Anyway if you want to send multiple data fragments in one HTTP request, then you can wrap it in a container that contains members for each piece of data:

```
{
    "connectionString" : "just-don't-do-that",
    "data" : {
        // the rest of the data
    }
}
```

Comment: this app will be used within a small circle, client need to enter the connection string and it will be saved in a xml file. Later the data from the xml file will be used to setup the connection string. Thats the requirement. Thats why I did that, is there any other ways to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @CodeCaster, it's really bad to send connection string from the client side.

To send multiple parameters from client side we need to have container what I mean by that is update your:

1) Data service class in my Xamarin app

```
public async void addSalesReport(string connstr, SalesReport salesReport)
{
    var data = {connstr: connstr,salesReport:salesReport}

    var content =  new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync("http://myserverdomain.com/api/SalesReport", content);

}
```

2) And Control to post data to Mysql db

```
[Route("api/SalesReport", Name = "salesReport")]
public void PostUpdate([FromBody]SalesReportData value)
{
    SalesDBConn db = new SalesDBConn();
    db.addSalesReport(value.connectionString, value.SalesReport);
}

//rename the class 
public class SalesReportData{
public string connectionString {get; set; }
public string SalesReport {get; set; }
}
```

I hope it helps... :)